# How to write if statement on button click

Tags: php, wordpress, button, onclick

Welcome!I would like to create a function in WordPress, which by pressing the check button the user is logged in or not. If a user is logged in, it moves to the "a", but if the user is offline, moves to the "b".

I have trouble implementing the function else if in the button.

Ruler code button in the cart.php file:

```
<a href="#"> class="button" CHECK OUT </a>
```

The code that checks whether the user is logged in:

```
if (is_user_logged_in () && isset ($ _ GET [ 'page_id']) && $ _ GET [ 'page_id']> 0 && get_option ('permalink_structure') == "" && $ _ GET [ 'page_id'] == woocommerce_get_page_id (' shop ')) {
     wp_redirect (get_post_type_archive_link ('product'));
     die ();
}
```

I have tried various options, but all failed.

Sample:
1.Click button ->
a. If a user is logged on - redirect to "http://a",
b. If user is logged out - redirect to "hhtp://b".

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook up with action hook before template starts to load. 
So, avoiding other conditions you have applied, general code for that would be

```
function redirect_on_login_status(){

  if( is_user_logged_in() ){ // you might want to put other conditions here
     wp_redirect( site_url('a') ); // change the site_url() part to you desired url, with this case it will be redirected to example.com/a
  }else{
     wp_redirect( site_url('b') );
  }
  exit();
}
add_action('wp','redirect_on_login_status');
```

Place this function to your theme's functions.php file. should work fine :)

Comment: You are wonderful! The only problem is that I want to make it work by pressing a button.
If I'm in the basket, I click on the "CHECK OUT" and then:
- If I am logged moves to a, but if you do it to b.

At this point, this function works on the entire page. Even I refresh page. I would like to make it work just by hitting the button.

How to implement this feature in the "CHECK OUT"
?